# C# XML nodes missing elements - Trying to save as CSV

Tags: c#, xml, csv, linq-to-xml

I have found many posts on saving XML as CSV, but my issue is that some nodes in my XML have fewer elements than others. This is causing my CSV columns to be off, which is not very helpful. The XML data that I am consuming is coming from a third party API.

Here is my code:

```
    internal static void XmlToCsvFile(XmlDocument doc, string fileName)
    {
        var xml = new XDocument();
        xml = XDocument.Parse(doc.InnerXml);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(100000);

        var xmlDocForHeaders = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocForHeaders.InnerXml = xml.Root.FirstNode.ToString();

        var xdocForHeaders = XDocument.Parse(xmlDocForHeaders.InnerXml);

        foreach (var element in xdocForHeaders.Elements().Elements())
        {
            sb.Append($"{element.Name},");
        }

        sb.Append("\n");

        foreach (XElement node in xml.Descendants("Table"))
        {
            foreach (XElement innerNode in node.Elements())
            {
                foreach (XElement elements in innerNode.Elements())
                {
                    sb.Append($"\"{elements.Value}\",");
                }

                sb.Append("\n");
            }

            sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
            sb.AppendLine();
        }

        var csvOut = sb.ToString();
        SaveDataToCsvFile(csvOut);
    }
```

I know I don't need to convert my XmlDocument to XDocument, but this seemed easier at the time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is a sample of the XML data:

```
<Table>
  <Record>
    <StoreID>43</StoreID>
    <StoreName>30455 Juniper</StoreName>
    <Disabled>0</Disabled>
    <Abbreviation>UC30455</Abbreviation>
    <ManagerEmployeeID>297</ManagerEmployeeID>
    <ManagerCommissionable>false</ManagerCommissionable>
    <Address>400 Green St.</Address>
    <City>Juniper</City>
    <StateProv>WA</StateProv>
    <ZipPostal>47895</ZipPostal>
    <Country>United States</Country>
    <PhoneNumber>8056954823</PhoneNumber>
    <FaxNumber>5085236524</FaxNumber>
    <DistrictNameJuniper South</DistrictName>
    <RegionName>High Hills Region</RegionName>
    <ChannelName>West Market</ChannelName>
    <StoreType>1/2 Tier-PP</StoreType>
    <GLCode>5862</GLCode>
    <SquareFootage>1100</SquareFootage>
    <LocationCode>MX029</LocationCode>
    <Latitude>49.5236458952</Latitude>
    <Longitude>-192.532150000</Longitude>
    <AddressVerified>Not Verified</AddressVerified>
    <TimeZone>(GMT-08:00) West Time (US &amp; Canada)</TimeZone>
    <AdjustDST>true</AdjustDST>
    <CashPolicy>Single-Drawer</CashPolicy>
    <MaxCashDrawer>0.0000</MaxCashDrawer>
    <Serial_on_OE>false</Serial_on_OE>
    <Phone_on_OE>true</Phone_on_OE>
    <PAW_on_OE>true</PAW_on_OE>
    <Comment_on_OE>false</Comment_on_OE>
    <HideCustomerAddress>false</HideCustomerAddress>
    <EmailAddress>donotreply@email.com</EmailAddress>
    <GeneralLocationNotes>Mon-Sat 9am-8pm, Sun 12pm-5pm</GeneralLocationNotes>
    <SaleInvoiceComment />
    <BankDetails />
    <Taxes>UT - Sales Tax 6.6%, 1.9% E911 Fee (WA)</Taxes>
    <Rent>0.0000</Rent>
    <PropertyTaxes>0.0000</PropertyTaxes>
    <InsuranceAmount>0.0000</InsuranceAmount>
    <OtherCharges>0.0000</OtherCharges>
    <DepositTaken>0.0000</DepositTaken>
    <LeaseNotes />
    <InsuranceCompany />
    <LandlordNotes />
    <LandlordName>COMPANY-JUNIPER/60144582</LandlordName>
    <UseLocationEmail>true</UseLocationEmail>
    <LocationEntityID>25367</LocationEntityID>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <StoreID>107</StoreID>
    <StoreName>9589 CLC Go Company.com</StoreName>
    <Disabled>0</Disabled>
    <Abbreviation>CL9589</Abbreviation>
    <ManagerEmployeeID>853</ManagerEmployeeID>
    <ManagerCommissionable>false</ManagerCommissionable>
    <Address>9852 Bland Banks Blvd.</Address>
    <City>Honneyton</City>
    <StateProv>MI</StateProv>
    <ZipPostal>69421</ZipPostal>
    <Country>USA</Country>
    <PhoneNumber>9595525214</PhoneNumber>
    <FaxNumber>3625485236</FaxNumber>
    <DistrictName>Recovery Services</DistrictName>
    <RegionName>zRetail Support</RegionName>
    <ChannelName>zRetail Support</ChannelName>
    <StoreType>Care Center</StoreType>
    <GLCode>0356</GLCode>
    <SquareFootage>2163</SquareFootage>
    <AddressVerified>Not Verified</AddressVerified>
    <TimeZone>(GMT-07:00) Central Time (US &amp; Canada)</TimeZone>
    <AdjustDST>true</AdjustDST>
    <CashPolicy>Single-Drawer</CashPolicy>
    <MaxCashDrawer>0.0000</MaxCashDrawer>
    <Serial_on_OE>false</Serial_on_OE>
    <Phone_on_OE>true</Phone_on_OE>
    <PAW_on_OE>false</PAW_on_OE>
    <Comment_on_OE>false</Comment_on_OE>
    <HideCustomerAddress>false</HideCustomerAddress>
    <EmailAddress>donotreply@email.com</EmailAddress>
    <GeneralLocationNotes />
    <SaleInvoiceComment />
    <BankDetails />
    <Taxes>MI - Honneyton</Taxes>
    <Rent>0.0000</Rent>
    <PropertyTaxes>0.0000</PropertyTaxes>
    <InsuranceAmount>0.0000</InsuranceAmount>
    <OtherCharges>0.0000</OtherCharges>
    <DepositTaken>0.0000</DepositTaken>
    <LeaseNotes />
    <InsuranceCompany />
    <LandlordNotes />
    <LandlordName />
    <UseLocationEmail>true</UseLocationEmail>
    <LocationEntityID>25397</LocationEntityID>
  </Record>
</Table>
```

As you can see, the first record contains lat and long elements, but the second does not. This throws everything off when converting to CSV.

Thanks again!

EDIT:

Here is what ended up working for me based on all your great comments!

```
internal static string XmlToCsvFile(XmlDocument doc, string fileName)
{
    var xml = XDocument.Parse(doc.InnerXml);

    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    var record = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (var element in xml.Descendants("Record").Elements())
    {
        if (!record.ContainsKey(element.Name.ToString()))
        {
            record.Add(element.Name.ToString(), "");
        }
    }

    foreach (var key in record.Keys)
    {
        sb.Append($"{key},");
    }

    sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
    sb.AppendLine();

    foreach (var node in xml.Descendants("Record"))
    {
        foreach (var key in record.Keys.ToList())
        {
            record[key] = "";
        }

        foreach (var elements in node.Elements())
        {
            record[elements.Name.ToString()] = elements.Value.ToString();
        }

        foreach (var value in record.Values)
        {
            sb.Append($"\"{value}\",");
        }

        sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
        sb.AppendLine();
    }

    var csvOut = sb.ToString();
    SaveDataToCsvFile(csvOut);

    return csvOut;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide sample xml?

Comment: Why not create a class to hold the data, and then parse the XML via LINQ to XML into the class, handling missing elements appropriately, and then write the collection of the classes out as a CSV?

Comment: Or even into an anonymous type which you can then process to the CSV file.

Comment: This is very clever. I need to add sub levels as well. Any idea how to do that? Something like a recursive function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick illustration of what I said in my comment.  Since you seem to be doing this in one shot, you can parse the XML into a collection of anonymous types, and then iterate through that collection to write out the CSV.

Simple example:

```
var records = xml.Descedants("Record").Select(r => new
              {
                  StoreID = (string)r.Element("StoreID"),
                  StoreName = (string)r.Element("StoreName"),
                  // other elements
              };
```

Note the explicit conversion to string - this will return null if the element is missing, which will resolve the issue with some elements missing in some records gracefully.  Otherwise you'll have to write a bunch of extra code to check for missing elements, which would get very ugly.

Once you have the collection of anonymous types, you can then iterate through them to write out the CSV:

```
foreach(var record in records)
{
    // Here you can access the individual properties in the currently selected record
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Your answer got me on the right track, but because I needed my keys to be dynamically created (CSV header to be dynamic) depending on the data coming in, I ended up using a dictionary to define how my data would look by iterating through all of my node keys and adding any new ones. Then I could add my data into the dictionary for each node. This seemed to work well, but I feel that it may be a little more messy than necessary. Any suggestions on cleaning it up would be greatly appreciated! Take a look at my edit above. Thanks again for all your help!!